# Putting generic parameter clazz to RealmQuery when parameter is getting from generic function overrited

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, realm, repository-pattern

Actually I'm writing a repository pattern with Kotlin for an Android Studio project. I have a generic interface named "BaseRepository". This interface is extended from "BaseRealmRepository" and others.

I need to get all results from Realm.db into findAll(), but I can't modify this inherited function because it is generic in other repositories.

When I try, I am getting the following error:

***"fun  findAllRealm
(
clazz: Class
)
: List
is not satisfied: inferred type GenericRealmModelType<*> is not a subtype of RealmModel"***

but my real problem is **clazz parameter of Class**, that **I need do cast or something** for pass to "where" clausule of realmQuery **without modify the generic function adding upper bounds like  or similar**

This is my generic interface:

```
interface BaseRepository<T> {

fun create(item: T) : T

fun remove(item: T)

fun update(item: T) : T

fun find(item: T): T

fun <T> findAll(clazz: Class<T>): List<T>

}
```

I'm created a generic type for do cast:

```
interface GenericRealmModelType<out T: RealmModel>{}
```

And finally, my abstract class "BaseObjectsRealmRepository" that is extended from "BaseRepository":

```
abstract class BaseObjectsRealmRepository<T> : BaseRepository<T> {

...

override fun <T> findAll(clazz:  Class<T>): List<T> {


     var klazz: Class<GenericRealmModelType<*>>  = clazz as Class<GenericRealmModelType<*>>

     val allResults =  findAllRealm(klazz)

     return allResults

}


private fun <T: RealmModel> findAllRealm(clazz: Class<T>): List<T>{

    val realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()

    val realmResults = realm
            .where(clazz) //CLAZZ IS MY PROBLEM
            .findAll()

    val allResults: List<T> = realm.copyFromRealm(realmResults)

    return allResults
}
}
```

The project configuration is the following:

Project build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.41'
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:5.1.0"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Module app build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

apply plugin: 'realm-android'

android {
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.example"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
core:3.0.2'


implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.12'
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.12'
kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.12'
kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.13'

implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
}

realm {
syncEnabled = true
}

repositories {
mavenCentral()
}





// Add to the bottom of the file
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

What can I do?

Thank you!

Comment: What *is* the purpose of `GenericRealmModelType`? `GenericRealmModelType` is not a `RealmModel`, so it cannot be queried against. You'd probably want the `T` you're passing, but you are overriding it with `GenericRealmModelType<*>` and I do not see what you hope to gain from doing that.

Comment: With "GenericRealmModelType" I wanted to create a generic type that inherited from RealmModel to avoid having to add the upper bound <T: RealmModel> to findAll(), function that I can't modify. I observed similar think in [Kotlin documentation - star projections](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#star-projections)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm get the solution for this:

BaseObjectsrealmRepository:

Change this:

Old:
    abstract class BaseObjectsRealmRepository : BaseRepository {

New:
    abstract class BaseObjectsRealmRepository constructor(clazz: Class): BaseRepository {

And now the next code:

```
override fun findAll(clazz:  Class<T>): List<T> {

     val allResults =  findAllRealm(clazz)

     return allResults

}


private fun findAllRealm(clazz: Class<T>): List<T>{


    val realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()

    val realmResults = realm
            .where(clazz)
            .findAll()

    val allResults: List<T> = realm.copyFromRealm(realmResults)

    return allResults
 }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can solve this problem by removing `interface GenericRealmModelType<out T: RealmModel>{}` entirely.

```
abstract class BaseObjectsRealmRepository<T> : BaseRepository<T> {

...

    override fun <T> findAll(clazz: Class<T>): List<T> =
        Realm.getDefaultInstance().use { r ->
            r.copyFromRealm(r.where(clazz).findAll())
        }
```

Comment: inlining the function and reifing the type you could get a clean `findAll<YourClass>()` function when calling it :D

Comment: Yeah I was thinking about that too, but he's overriding so I didn't go into that

Comment: @EpicPandaForce if I remove genericRealmModelType and pass directly the clazz parameter, I get this error : **Type parameter bound for T in 

fun <T : RealmModel> findAllRealm
(
clazz: Class<T#1 (type parameter of com.example.example.data.realm.repository.BaseObjectsRealmRepository.findAllRealm)>
)
: List<T#1>
is not satisfied: inferred type T is not a subtype of RealmModel**

Comment: How can I do casting the clazz parameter like .where(<T: RealmModel> clazz).findAll()?

Comment: Oh. Right. You can try `r.where(clazz as Class<RealmModel>).findAll()`